# database lost connection when publishing shiny in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, odbc, dbi, shinyapps

The connection to an access databases with odbc works just fine when running the app locally on my laptop, however, when I attempt to publish it in shinyapps.io the application crashes and get a blank page with the following:

An error has occurred

The application failed to start.

exit status 1

```
library(shiny)
library(odbc)
library(DBI)

#Connection works on my laptop as expected
dbpath <- paste0(getwd(),"/RBDD.accdb");dbpath
myDB <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), .connection_string=paste0("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=",dbpath))
dbListTables(myDB)
Sample <- dbReadTable(myDB, "Sample")
Sample$SampleDate <- as.Date(Sample$SampleDate,"%m/%d/%Y")
Catch <- dbReadTable(myDB,"Catch")
joined <- left_join(Catch,Sample,by="SampleRowID")
```

Question:
How do I transfer the above connection to shinyapps.io?
I have been reading quite a lot but I am still struggling to make the connection.

[image]

Comment: Are you certain that the shinyapps.io server has that ODBC driver available? (I would actually expect "not".) Try checking `odbc::odbcListDataSources()` and `odbc::odbcListDrivers()` to see what data sources and drivers are available on the remote server; since you likely don't have shell access, add that as a debugging log statement and re-upload the app.

Comment: I see the drivers there when typing `odbc::odbcListDrivers()` on the R console. The odbc driver that I am using is: `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)`. See pic above. How do I debug a log statement?

Comment: I don't think shinyapps.io supports MS Access db's. You can find a list of available drivers and more details on how to use `odbc` with shinyapps.ui [here](https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/applications.html#using-the-odbc-package).

Comment: That would be strange if shinyapps.io doesn't support shiny apps published with MS Access databases. Access is widely used still. But that's possible.

Comment: Here's the list of odbc databases supported by shinyapps.io from https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/applications.html: "Athena"  
 "BigQuery"   "Cassandra"  "Hive"       "Impala"     "MongoDB"    "MySQL"     
  "Netezza"    "PostgreSQL" "Redshift"   "Salesforce" "Snowflake"  "SQLServer" 
 "Teradata" `

Comment: Fair enough. I will need to find a way to migrate my 0.5 million records to another database. Are any of these databases that are supported by shinyapps.io open source or are all commercial databases?

Comment: @Salvador I certainly wouldn't go as far as saying "Access is widely used still". From my experience, here in AU the use of MS Access in the private and gov sectors is rare (and largely due to legacy systems). As to open source vs. commercial db's: You need to do some research. SQL has open-source flavours (SQLite) and is used in various db's (like Amazon's Athena); MongoDB and TerraData are open-source; and so on.

Comment: When I suggested listing drivers/sources, I should have stressed more the *"remote server"*, since running it on your console has zero applicability to deployed apps. I agree against *"Access is widely used"*. In addition to SQLite, you may also consider [`duckdb`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/duckdb/index.html). It is similar to SQLite in that it is a single-file serverless database, but it can allegedly be a bit faster, and has direct support for more data types (SQLite supports a lot, though most of them are just stored as strings or numbers).

Comment: One applicable comparison of SQLite with DuckDB (with performance in mind): https://uwekorn.com/2019/10/19/taking-duckdb-for-a-spin.html.

Comment: SQLite looks promising. Is it supported by shiniapps.io? I don't see it listed here: https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/applications.html

Comment: Why not export to CSV file? Pretty much any DB can handle that format.

Comment: With SQLite and DuckDB, you don't need the `odbc` package, you can use the `RSQLite` or `duckdb` packages directly.

Comment: Ok, I found a way to transfer tables from Ms Access to RSQLite with a couple of lines of R code.  Is RSQLite supported by shinyapps.io?

Comment: “*Is RSQLite supported by shinapps.io*” Yes. RSQLite is serverless so you don’t need anything other than the db file on your remote system and `RSQLite` to access. Mind you, if persistent storage is your goal and you want to allow users to edit data in the db, the situation gets more complicated.

Comment: I don't want users to edit or change anything in db. I just want them to use a shiny app that displays tables and graphics with the source being the RSQlite database. Thanks all for your advice, I think I am getting somewhere now. I was also thinking about querying my Access database and creating a large csv file and deploy it with the shiny app onto shinyapps.io. But will try RSQlite first and see how it goes. Thanks again all.